# Como centralizar um card panel no materialize css?

Tags: css, materialize

Tenho o seguinte formulário de login dentro de um card panel:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu poderia fazer para centralizar o meu card na página?

Este é o código que tenho até o momento:

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
  <input id="user_name" type="text" class="validate" required>
  <label for="user_name">Usuário</label>
</div>

<div class="input-field col s12">
  <input id="password" type="password" class="validate" required>
  <label for="password">Senha</label>
</div>

<div class="switch">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="lever"></span> Mantanha-me conectado
  </label>
</div>

<div class="input-field col s12">
  <br>
</div>

<div class="input-field col s12">
  <button class="waves-effect waves-light btn" type="submmit">Login
  </button>
</div>

<div class="input-field col s12">
  <a href="#">Ainda não é membro? Crie já uma conta!</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Você deseja centralizar o card todo na página? E também seria necessário ver o html completo, você só postou o html referente aos elementos DENTRO do card.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o [`offset`](http://materializecss.com/grid.html) para te ajudar nessa tarefa:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s4 offset-s4 card">
    <!-- SEUS FIELDS -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Segue o <kbd>**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/buh159/55L52yww/8/)**</kbd>.

Você pode tentar também na <s>força bruta</s>:

```
.card {
     position: absolute;
     left: 50%;
     top: 50%;
     -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
     -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
     -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
     -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```